# Twilio disconnecting outgoing call after custom message

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using the Twilio Python SDK to make outgoing calls. I am using Twilio Voice streams to capture the conversation in real-time and generate transcripts. However, after initiating the call and when the user picks up, there is a custom message that says "Thanks for the call. Configure your number's voice URL to change this message. Let us know if we can help you in any way during your development."

The call then gets disconnected after 11 seconds, even if the other person is still speaking.

How can I remove this custom message? Also, how can I prevent my call from getting disconnected when I am just listening to the other person speak and not saying much myself?

I have a paid Twilio account and am no longer on a trial. But it still seems to be enforcing some trial restrictions with the short call limits and audio messages.

This is how I am making a call :

```
client = Client(username=account_sid,password=auth_token)


def make_a_call():
    call_status_url = f'https://{ngrok_domain}/call-status'
    call = client.calls.create(url='https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
                           to=to_number,
                           from_=from_number,
                           status_callback=call_status_url,
                           status_callback_event=['initiated','answered','completed'],
                           status_callback_method='POST',
                           timeout=600
                        )
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_a_call()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]

In your code, you are using this url: https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/

Open that url in a browser. You will find it is returning:

```
<Response>
<Say voice="woman">Thanks for the call. Configure your number's voice U R L to change this message.</Say>
<Pause length="1"/>
<Say voice="woman">Let us know if we can help you in any way during your development.</Say>
</Response>
```

If you don't want that Twiml, you will need to produce other Twiml. [Twiml](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) is the language that Twilio uses for instructions on how to handle calls.

As a starting point, check out the [Programmable Voice Quickstarts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart).

Comment: but I am making outbound calls . will this work same for outbound calls ?

Comment: Open this url in a browser: https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/, this is the url you have specified in your code. This url is returning Twiml that is returning the message you are hearing. You need to generate other Twiml if you want the call to do other others.